# Waypoints.js file inclusion issue

Tags: jquery

I have code to grab a scroll event and move some divs around. The problem is that the js file isn't being pulled in by the document.ready() function.  It only gets pulled in when the page is resized.  Here is my JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var tabContainerHeight = $('.tabContainer').outerHeight(true);
    var origTblWidth;
    console.log('inside ready func');
    $('#origTbl').waypoint({
        handler: function(event, direction) {
        if(direction === "down"){
            origTblWidth = $('#origTbl').width();
            $('#tHeader').addClass('sticky');
            $('#tHeader').width(origTblWidth);
            $('.sticky').css('top', tabContainerHeight);
            $('#tHeader').removeClass('elHide');
        }else{
            $('#tHeader').addClass('elHide');
            $('#origTbl tr:first-child').removeClass('sticky');
        }
        console.log('waypoint reached');
    }
  });

  $(window).on('resize', function(){
      origTblWidth = $('#origTbl').width();
      $('#tHeader').width(origTblWidth);
  });
});
```

The first console message shows up on page load but the second one does not.  Only on a page re-size does the second message show.  Any ideas?

Comment: "the js file isn't being pulled" where is the code for including a js file?

Comment: Could you give a fiddle reproducing your problem?

Comment: Its in the jsp as follows:

Comment: <tiles:insert page='/gui_template.jsp' flush='true'>  
  <tiles:put name='extraHead' type='string'>
    <framework:resource version="1.8.3" name="jquery" type="script"/>
  <framework:resource version="1.9.2" name="jquery-ui" type="script"/>
  <framework:resource project="gui" subproject="common" name="common-jquery-ui" type="style"/>
  <framework:resource version="1.5.0" type="script" name="jquery.hoverIntent"/>
  <framework:resource version="1.1.7" name="waypoints" type="script"/>

Comment: Anyone else able to help at all?   Still stuck on this one. Thanks!!!

Comment: Due to reglatory requirements Im unable to include a fiddle.